# The Schema at the Publisher does not match the Subscriber

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I have a merge replication setup and added a view to the publisher, I also added this view under articles.

The Schema was created and it also created the view on the subscriber side.

Since then I get the following error:

> The schema at the Publisher (version: 331 and guid:
>   '72A98308-16D2-4439-AAC0-C5B11BDAF47D') does not match the schema at
>   the Subscriber (version: 331 and guid:
>   '1206D63D-7430-4048-A9DC-125C959892CE'). This can occur after the
>   Publisher has been restored from a backup. In this case, recreate the
>   initial snapshot and reinitialize all subscriptions.

I traced it under the sysmergeschemachange table and it points to the same view just created.

How do I clear it?

Thank you

Comment: I would desperately like to avoid  going the reinitialize route

Comment: What I noticed now is that the sysmergeschemachange table on the publisher have 3 more schema versions than on the Subscribers.